# How can I use multible terraform tf files in one jenkins script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I am trying to learn terraform usage with jenkins. I realized that I can not use 2 tf files in the same github repository.I have 2 tf files: Providers.tf and Provider2.tf

Provider.tf:

```
#OpenShot Terraform Project
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket-leanscale-2"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {a
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}


resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld-leanscale-2"
  }
}
```

Provider2.tf:

```
#OpenShot Terraform Project
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b2" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket-leanscale-3"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket2"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu2" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}


resource "aws_instance" "web2" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu2.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld-leanscale-3"
  }
}
```

Jenkins Script :

````
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        
        terraform 'terraform-leanscale'
    }
    
      environment {
    TF_WORKSPACE = 'default' //Sets the Terraform Workspace
    TF_IN_AUTOMATION = 'true'
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "${params.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "${params.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Git Checkout') {
            steps {
               git branch: 'staging', credentialsId: 'leanscale', url: 'https://github.com/yusufkaratoprak/leanscale_yusuf.git'
            }
        }
        
        stage('terraform-init') {
            steps {
                sh label: '', script: 'terraform init' 
            }
        }
        
        stage('terraform-apply') {
            steps {
                sh label: '', script: 'terraform apply --auto-approve' 
            }
        }
        
    }
}



```C
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform init
[31mThere are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.[0m[0m
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mArgument or block definition required[0m

[0m  on provider.tf line 24, in data "aws_ami" "ubuntu":
  24:   filter {[4ma[0m
[0m
An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
[0m[0m
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mDuplicate provider configuration[0m

[0m  on provider2.tf line 2:
   2: [4mprovider "aws"[0m {
[0m
A default (non-aliased) provider configuration for "aws" was already given at
provider.tf:2,1-15. If multiple configurations are required, set the "alias"
argument for alternative configurations.
[0m[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (terraform-apply)
Stage "terraform-apply" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
````

```
How can OI use multiple tf files in the same repository by Jenkins script?
```

Comment: What's the difference between these two tf files? They look very similar? They have same provider.

Comment: Hi; if you look at it very carefully, you will see that differently named ec2 and s3 version.

Comment: They have different name tags. They are not simliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this declaration in its own file instead of duplicating

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-2"
}
```

Terraform doesn't care if you use one or 100 files for the code, but definitions must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly looking at that TF code it could all be run in the same file with just one provider block as there is nothing to require it to be in two separate files.

If you wanted the logical separation of resources you would move the provider block (that is the same in both files) to another file, probably called `provider.tf` and then have `resources1.tf` and `resources2.tf` (or whatever Terraform doesnt care so long as it has a `.tf` extension.

However, if you wanted it to be in two files with two providers for whatever reason, Terraform allows aliasing of providers so that you can have more than one of the same provider
see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html#alias-multiple-provider-configurations

OR if you didnt want to change the code files at all

In your Pipeline you could rename provider2, run the stages for provider1.  Clean up the `.terraform` folder, rename provider1 and set provider2 back to its proper name and run the stages for that file.

OR

Put them in different Directories in the Git repo

You can then use the `dir` command to change into each directory and run the Terraform

```
dir("provider1"){
   sh "terraform init"
   sh "terraform apply"
```

TBH the correct answer is the first..... to move the provider out to its own file.

**Edit**:
You are also getting an error for line 24 of providers.tf due to the extra `a` on the line

```
filter {a
```

Answer (score 1):

As looking in to your terraform code provider is same for both the files. so avoid redundancy by creating provider.tf and write only

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-2"
}
```

next Instead of writing your code in separate two files use modules structure.
write a single file with above code  in a module directory by giving some
awsinstance.tf

```
    enter code here
    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b2" {
      bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket-leanscale-3"
      acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket2"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu2" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}


resource "aws_instance" "web2" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu2.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld-leanscale-3"
  }
}
```

, and instead of passing values directly  use variable.tf in that directory.
like

```
    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b2" {
      bucket = var.bucketname
      acl    = var.acl

}
```

and in variable file

```
variable "bucketname"{
}
```

mention all the variables
and then in main.tf use the module "any name" and give the source as above file and pass required parameters. and also mention variable.tf here also and pass values using

```
variable.tfvars

variable bucketname = ""my-tf-test-bucket-leanscale-3"
```